# Proof of edge-order inequality

Tags: graph-theory

I was just going through a past exam paper for my intro graphs module and the following question came up, and I can't find any notes on it:

Let G = (V,E) be a simple graph. Show that:

$2|E| \leq |V|^2 - |V|$

any ideas?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot

Answer (score 1):

Equality holds for complete graphs.  Since $G$ is simple, it's the subgraph of some complete graph $K_n$.  So $|E(G)| \leq |E(K_n)|$ and the inequality follows.

Answer (score 0):

Cp. Bondy/Murty "Graph Theory with Applications", Ex. 1.1.3 (so it must be easy), available online ... but you do know what a simple graph is ? (Probably the question does not really belong here, being of such a trivial nature ?) Kind regards, Stephan.